# Mongoose Validation pre-hook vs schematype

Tags: validation, mongoose

The question seems stupid but I can't find an answer...

What is the difference between pre-hook validation and SchemaType validation? I first used pre-hook middleware to do my validation but after readding the doc I saw that I could do the same on the schemaType.

I call schemaType validation this kind of validation:

```
var validateLogin = function (login, res) {
    res(login === 'foo');
}

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    login: {
        type: String,
        required: '{PATH} is required',
        validate: [validateLogin, '{PATH} must be foo']
    }
});
```

In the mongoose doc I can see.

> Validation is defined in the SchemaType

Does that mean that we should use the schemaType way as much as possible?
What is the real diffèrence?

Comment: I can only think of being able to validate the document at all time and not only on save

Answer (score 1):

The built-in SchemaType validations are fairly limited in what they can check for, although they are usually good enough for 80% or more of the validation you want to do.

The pre-save hook allows you to do much more complex validation.  You could check, as a contrived example, that a given number is prime or divisible by 3.

You can also check consistency **between fields**.  For example, perhaps you could check that a  zip code/postal code matches the state/province the user entered.